# Signal seems to be not connected

Tags: django, django-signals

I am using Django 3.0.8.

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'admin_aux.apps.AdminAuxConfig', # PROJECT_APPS
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AdminAuxConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'admin_aux'

    def ready(self):
        import admin_aux.allauth_avatar # Breakpoint. Stopps here when the server is run.
```

**admin_aux/allauth_avatar.py**

```
@receiver(user_signed_up) # Breakpoint. Doesn't stop here when the server is run.
def on_user_signed_up(sender, request, *args, **kwargs):
    sociallogin = kwargs.get('sociallogin')
    if sociallogin:
        copy_avatar(request,
                    sociallogin.account.user,
                    sociallogin.account)
```

Problem: the receiver doesn't receive the signal.

I marked breakpoints in the code.

When I run debugging in PyCharm, I expect that the interpreter will stop at the breakpoint in allauth_avatar.py. But it doesn't. So, signal seems to be not connected. How can I resolve this?

Comment: at what point do you want this function to be called? on save, post save... ext?

Comment: It is about user signup via django-allauth.

Comment: from allauth doc :  "Sent when a user signs up for an account. This signal is typically followed by a user_logged_in, unless e-mail verification prohibits the user to log in."
are you set ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none' ?

Comment: try: `from admin_aux.allauth_avatar import *`